# Passing the $in operator with result of previous column

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I had a document like this:

```
const myUser = 'e'

//Collection Selection
{
 level: [
   {
     currentUser: 'f',
     stages: [
      {
        users: ['a','b','c']
      },
      {
        users: ['b','d','e']
      }
     ]
   },
   {
     currentUser: 'g',
     stages: [
      {
        users: ['y','x','w']
      },
      {
        users: ['x','v','f']
      }
     ]
   }
 ]
}
```

I want to select the `level`s where `myUser` is in at least one of the `stage`s or is the `currentUser`, so I'm making a query like this:

```js
Selection.aggregate()
.addFields({myUser})
.addFields({allUsers: {   // flattening all arrays into [a,b,c,b,d,e,y,x,w,x,v,f]
  $reduce: {
     input: {
        $reduce: {
           input: $level.stages.users,
           initialValue: [],
           in: { $concatArrays: ['$$value', '$$this'] }
        },
     initialValue: [],
     in: { $concatArrays: ['$$value', '$$this'] }
     }
   }}})
match({
   $or: [
     {
       myUser: myUser
     },
     {
        myUser: {$in: '$allUsers'}
     }
    ]
 })
```

and I don't know why I get an

> $in requires an array

error message. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$expr`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) to compare fields in a document.

```
{
  $expr: {
    $in: [
      "$myUser",
      "$allUsers"
    ]
  }
}
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xajSeENeXxx)

---

Mongoose

```
.match({
    $or: [
      {
        myUser: "e"
      },
      {
        $expr: {
          $in: [
            "$myUser",
            "$allUsers"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found out doing this works as well:

```
.addField({myUser})
.match({
    $or: [
      {
        myUser: "e"
      },
      {
        "level.stages.users": myUser
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Comment: Yes, this is another approach and with this, you don't need to create `allUsers` field for filter.